# openstack nova : InvalidArchitectureName: Architecture name 'arm' is not recognized

Tags: fedora, openstack

On Fedora-18,  I Installed devstack and when I try to start nova compute I get this error message :
Any thoughts on whats going wrong.

```
$ uname -a
Linux qabot 3.7.2-201.fc18.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 11 22:16:23 UTC 2013 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

> 2014-12-29 18:54:25.206 TRACE
>   nova.openstack.common.threadgroup
>   File
>   "/opt/stack/nova/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py",
>   line 4591, in
>   _get_instance_capabilities 2014-12-29 18:54:25.206 TRACE
>   nova.openstack.common.threadgroup
>   arch.canonicalize(g.arch), 2014-12-29
>   18:54:25.206 TRACE
>   nova.openstack.common.threadgroup
>   File
>   "/opt/stack/nova/nova/compute/arch.py",
>   line 160, in canonicalize 2014-12-29
>   18:54:25.206 TRACE
>   nova.openstack.common.threadgroup
>   raise
>   exception.InvalidArchitectureName(arch=name)
>   2014-12-29 18:54:25.206 TRACE
>   nova.openstack.common.threadgroup
>   InvalidArchitectureName: Architecture
>   name 'arm' is not recognised
>   2014-12-29 18:54:25.206 TRACE
>   nova.openstack.common.threadgroup

[Complete logs here](http://pastebin.com/FPFXwYVz)

Comment: The first thing that's wrong is you installed Fedora 18. Start over with a current Fedora release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least  `Fedora 20` to install openstack. `Fedora 18` is not supported.

Other Supported Operating systems:

Ubuntu 14.04
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7
CentOS 7
openSUSE 13.1
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3

Comment: Please add the URL to the source